# Cannot locate VBA module

Tags: excel, vba

Good day.

I recorded a VBA code for my excel some minutes ago.  I need to edit it but could not find it in the list of modules.  The code still runs whenever I click the shortcuts I created for it but I cannot locate it.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in each of the individual sheets? Macros can be in individual sheets (Sheet1, 2, 3 etc in the example below, as well as listed under Modules.

Excel VBA code is usually recorded in a module like Module 1, however you may be looking in the VBA code for another workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is located in PERSONAL.xlsm ?